# MonoTouch: Where is Frame.Origin?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, cgrect

I am trying to translate this centering code snip in Objective-C into MonoTouch

```
imageView.frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds) - 
            CGRectGetMidX(imageView.bounds)
```

But can't find where `Origin` is.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

MonoTouch maps `GCRect` to `System.Drawing.RectangleF` since it's closer to what .NET developers have been using (e.g. System.Drawing / Windows Forms...).

As such `imageView.frame.origin.x` will become `imageView.Frame.Location.X` which can simplified by `imageView.Frame.X`.

If you add `using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;` to your source file you'll get extension methods that will provide you with `CGRectGetMidX` replacement, e.g.

```
views.Bounds.GetMidX ()
```

So

```
imageView.frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(imageView.bounds);
```

should become

```
imageView.Frame.X = view.Bounds.GetMidX () - imageView.Bounds.GetMidX ();
```

Comment: Does `CGRect.Size.Width` maps with `CGRect.Width` also?